# Alternate he / she in text

Tags: macros, conditionals

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`he-she`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/he-she)

I have seen a book that instead of using the masculine pronoun (he, his, etc.) alternates the gender ('he' then 'she' then next time 'he' again).

Is there a way to do this with LaTeX - to use a placeholder that alternates between two predefined words?

(I'm looking for a pointer as to where to start.)

EDIT: There is a useful discussion in the comments to Martin's answer for how to relax the strict he/she alternate (which can be confusing if applied too strictly).

Comment: I fully support the use of [singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) instead.  It avoids the problems with the gendered words; it's used in actual speech; it's the clearest option; and it's attested as far back as 1300, having been used by such notable authors as Chaucer and Shakespeare.  Prescriptivism can go hang :-)

Comment: If you (unlike me) don't like Antal's suggestion, here's another one: Just use "she". This is also a lot clearer than switching.

Comment: Just use *he* for every odd and *she* for every even chapter (or vice versa). It's the most simplest, least intrusive method which still is 100% "political correct".

Comment: Based on the discussion below, I've now implemented my solution as a package: [he-she](http://ctan.org/pkg/he-she).

Comment: @Alan thanks for this - Also I have never put latex code into a package, your package provides a great example for me as to how to go about it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Following up on the discussion about how to get this to work in practice, here's a modification to Josef's solution which allows one to use anaphoric pronouns linked to the current state.  Pronominal anaphora is quite complicated, so even this solution would only work for a limited set of cases, but it would still be a bit of an improvement.

**Update:** I've implemented this solution as the [`he-she`](http://ctan.org/pkg/he-she) package.

The problem arises in sentences like the following:

1. If someone thinks \heshe is sick, he should go to the doctor.

(As Norman notes, it's perfectly colloquiual English to use 'they' for these sorts of pronouns, but since that's not up for debate here, we'll soldier on :-) )

In sentence (1) we need the pronoun in the main clause to match in gender with the pronoun in the 'if'-clause.  If we use the `\heshe` macro we won't know what the gender is, however, since it will change depending on how many times it has previously been used.

So we really need *two* macros: one for the switch, and one for anaphoric reference to the current gender state.  I've implemented this simply by creating one extra macro within Josef's solution (of course the same idea works for Martin's as well.)

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \newif\ifhe\hetrue
    \newcommand*\heshe%
    {%
      \ifhe%
        he%
        \global\hefalse%
      \else%
        she%
        \global\hetrue%
      \fi%
    \xspace
    }%
    \newcommand*\he%
    {\ifhe%
        she
      \else%
        he%
      \fi
    \xspace
    }
    \begin{document}

If someone thinks \heshe is sick \he should go to a doctor immediately.
When \he goes to the the doctor, \heshe can figure out the problem.
\end{document}
```

This is a more linguistically useful version than restricting the scope of the change to a single sentence, since in the second sentence of the source example, there are two instances of a pronoun: the first is anaphoric to the previous sentence (and so should match in gender, but the second can be assigned a new gender.)

[image: Output of sample document:]

Comment: The `\xspace` must be the last command in the macros. It looks ahead (using `\@ifnextchar`, i.e. `\futurelet`) to see if it has to produce a space or not. Here it only sees `\global`, `\else` or `\fi`.

Comment: @Martin Thanks. I had just copied Josef's code.  (Ironically, there are no places in which the nominative pronoun woul be followed by punctuation anyway except in the very prescriptive (and linguistically crazy) "John is taller than he.").

Comment: Ironic indeed. In that case it a normal `\space` should do it.

Comment: Hmm..what about "He, being taller than her, was able to reach the cookie jar."

Comment: @BeSlayed I knew claiming 'no places' would come back to bite me. :-)  Since the `\xspace` does no real harm, it's fine to leave it in. (It does, however, pose other problems: for example `\emph{\heshe},` will yield ' *he* , ' which is undesirable.)

Answer (score 16):

You can do this by defining an *if-switch* which toggles every time it is used:

```
\newif\iffemale
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand*\heorshe{%
   \iffemale
      she
      \global\femalefalse% next one is male
   \else
      he
      \global\femaletrue% next one is female
   \fi
   \xspace
}

% Capitalized version:
\newcommand*\Heorshe{%
   \iffemale
      She
      \global\femalefalse
   \else
      He
      \global\femaletrue
   \fi
   \xspace
}
```

**edits:** Added missing `\global` and `\xspace`.

Comment: Haha latex is cool!  Thank you Martin, just testing it now, I thought it would be a lot more complicated - I need to look up that \newif command. I have never seen that before.  Thanks!

Comment: I was going to add a similar answer but using counters instead of booleans. Yours is much clear.

Comment: That is not enough because you will need pronouns, posessive pronouns and all kind of other elements that depend on a gender. And they have to be aligned within once sentence. Therefore you have to switch at the end of a sentence and not at every use. I think it would be cool to have an `\either{this/that}` macro that picks either the first or the second choice and reverses that choice at the end of a sentence. This way you need just one macro (or maybe a second for the switching) and don't specialized macros for every case.

Comment: @Christian: How do you do if you want `\either{this/that}` to be first `this` but `\either{he/she}` to be second `she`?

Comment: @Christian: You are of course right. But it is exactly what Tom was asking about (not what I most likely needs). I heard about such books. Normally they change the gender only once per chapter. In this case you still need more macros but they can be simply set to the correct value at the begin of the chapter.

Comment: @Leo My idea is that you write a sentence like this: `\either{He/She} left the house and went to \either{his/her} car`. To make any sense, I believe you have to consistently pick the first or the second choice within the sentence. However, in the next sentence you might pick the other choice (again, consistently). But might have misunderstood the intention of the question and @Tom wants to switch choices really at every possible occasion. That would lead to very difficult to read text. I'd design `\either` in a way that the switch is toggled at every `\par`.

Comment: You could use a macro at the begin of every sentence which needs to use a gender-specific word. This macro then toggles the gender.

Comment: @Christian: I think that if you're aiming for consistency, you need to be even more careful than that: pronouns often link sentences together and change meaning based on the appearance of other subjects.  However, the point of the switching is to be gender-neutral even at the possible cost of being confusing, so I don't know about `\either`.  In my opinion, this form of gender-neutrality is forced (if whimsical); either stick unapologetically to "he", go blatantly with "she", or use the time-honored "they".  I prefer the last one.

Comment: @Martin: to switch at every sentence, I would make `.` active and define it to do the relevant things.

Comment: @Bruno: Sure, that was also my first idea. That wouldn't be very difficult, but was happens when the `.` is needed somewhere else, like in `\fboxsep=1.23pt`? That would break horrible!

Comment: @Martin: make `=` active, and define it to read the following digits and dots expandably... `\def={\expandafter\EQ\string}` and `\def\EQ#1{\ifx#1\egroup\iffalse{\fi\expandafter}\fi}`. Ok, it need to check for many other cases, but it _could_ be done.

Comment: Thinking about it, I realize that it is probably better to use a star to mean "change the gender". I.e. `\He did \his job so well that \he* got what \he* expected` would give "She did her job so well that he got what she expected"... ok, that sounds odd, but it is because I needed to pu enough * in a short space.

Comment: Let me add my 2 cents worth as a linguist. To make this work in a linguistically sensible way (apart from needing different case forms for he/him/his) what you need is *two* commands.  One which changes the gender, and then a second one which is anaphoric to the current gender state. This allows you to have strings of pronouns across sentences without screwing up the gender.  So  adopting Bruno's notation, the idea would be that `\he*` would change the gender (and set the gender flag) and then `\he` would expand to either 'he' or 'she' depending on the current gender choice.

Comment: (Run out of space in the previous comment.) I've added another answer showing how this would work in practice.

Comment: Even Alan Munn's suggestion is not quite going to work, since if you have a paragraph describing a scenario with three different generic individuals interacting, you need to keep the genders consistent for each of them. What you really need is some sort of system for linking several different pronouns, so that latex knows to use the same gender for all of them (and perhaps alternates genders for linked systems of pronouns, according to the first occurrence of each). I'm thinking you would have a command like `\pronoun{Their}{student27}` that would show up as either "His" or "Her"...

Comment: ...depending on whether `student27` was assigned to be male or female.

Comment: @Charles Of course, you're right, which is why in my answer I hedged with the "anaphora is complicated" and "it won't cover all the cases" :-) Given the questionable nature of the entire goal of the question, it's not clear how complicated a system you really want. In practice your system would probably add unnecessary complication since the need to keep track of different first occurrences would be quite limited. (I.e, for most cases, the scope of the assigned name would be limited to a paragraph or two, rather than the whole document.)

Comment: @Alan Munn: Fair enough. I came up with "my" system more out for intellectual interest than practical value; I doubt I would use it even if someone implemented it.

Answer (score 13):

I tried hard but Martin was faster ;-)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newif\ifhe\hetrue
\newcommand*\heshe%
{%
  \ifhe%
    he%
    \global\hefalse%
  \else%
    she%
    \global\hetrue%
  \fi%
  \xspace
}%
\begin{document}
First \heshe is a man, but then \heshe turns into a woman. And back again: \heshe
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, but you remembered to add `\xspace`. :-)

Comment: You need to add `\global` like in my code. Otherwise the gender will be local inside environments.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more sensible to put the \xspace at the end of the macro (before `}`) instead of inside each branch of the `if`?

Comment: @Paŭlo: Not just more sensible. The `\xspace` macro looks ahead to decide whether to add a space or not. All what it sees here is `\global` (or `\he...` in the original version). It must be at the very end in order to work. See my answer.

Answer (score 8):

It's not an answer to your question, really, as much as a clever evasion, but *The Joy of TeX* deals with it by inventing new epicene pronouns, which I at least think counts as stylish (if perhaps not to be too eagerly imitated).

Thus E, Em, and Eir instead of he/she, him/her, and other abominations.

Just so I'm not being completely irrelevant, an alternative technique to the fine existing answers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\def\heshei{he\xspace
  \global\let\heshe\hesheii
}
\def\hesheii{she\xspace
  \global\let\heshe\heshei
}
\let\heshe\hesheii % ladies first

\begin{document}
Orlando: first \heshe is a woman, then \heshe is a man, and then \heshe is back
again.
\end{document}
```

Nothing wrong with 'they' as a suitable pronoun.

Comment: I've tried this. It's difficult to deal with capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

Here several years later with an alternative proposal.  Doing this automatically presents some tricky corner cases.  Take this gender-neutral Alice-and-Bob example:

> **Alice** asked **Bob** to move **Bob’s** car out of **Alice’s** driveway.  **Bob** told **Alice** that the driveway was as much **Bob’s** as **Alice’s**, so **Alice** could go love **herself**.

If you replaced all the names with pronouns, you would get:

> **She** asked **him** to move **his** car out of **her** driveway.  **He** told **her** that the driveway was as much **his** as **hers**, so **she** could go love **herself**.

Three things we immediately notice:

- There are five cases for the personal pronouns in this English paragraph: subject, object, possessive, absolute possessive, and reflexive.
- Any of them can appear in uppercase or lowercase.
- The pronouns do *not* always alternate.  There are two characters, distinguished by gender.

The existing `he-she` package can handle anaphoric pronouns for one person, but if you try to mix `\him` and `\her` (or `\his` and `\hir` or `\hiss` and `\hers`), they will all be the same gender until the next paragraph.  The only way to write about two example characters with different genders is to constantly flip the gender toggle, which is difficult to read and error-prone.

The logic gets even more complex if we need to, for example, remember the arbitrary gender of a character later.  (Think back to our poor student in Section 1.  **She** ....)

And introducing even a few words from any language with gram­mat­i­cal gender complicates things a lot.  (Fiancé/Fiancée, for example.)

The most useful thing you can do with this—which, with respect to singular *they* or Spivak pronouns, you can’t do as fluently with them—is that you have a made-up example with two people, who use different pronouns.  Then you don’t have to keep using their names or circumlocutions like “the former” or ”the second one.”  In that use case, there are only two people to keep track of.  Luckily, there are two permutations of **he**/**she**, **her**/**his**, and so on.  So, you could define commands `\heshe`, `\shehe`, `\HerHis`, `\HisHer`, etc.  Adding a star would then swap the current character’s gender.  The genders of commands will remain consistent (if `\SheHe` expands to `She`, `\hisher` will expand to `his`, and so on) until the next starred command swaps them all.

So, the source code for that example would look like:

```
\SheHe* asked \himher to move \hisher car out of
\herhis driveway. \HeShe told \herhim that the
driveway was as much \hishers as \hershis, so
\shehe could go love \herhimself.
```

This could be built from a more general command that selects based on the last character’s gender, which would also be useful in and of itself:

```
\gendered{fiancé}{fiancée}
```

#### A “Simple” implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine} % For example.

%% Simple pronoun alternation:

\usepackage{xspace, suffix}
\makeatletter

\newif\ifpronouns@feminine
\pronouns@femininefalse

\newcommand{\gendered}[2]{%
  \ifpronouns@feminine%
    {#2}%
  \else {#1}%
  \fi}

\WithSuffix\newcommand\gendered*[2]{%
  \ifpronouns@feminine%
    \pronouns@femininefalse%
  \else%
    \pronouns@femininetrue%
  \fi%
  \gendered{#1}{#2}}

%% This could really be automated to generate the eight forms of each pair of
%% pronouns, along the capital/lowercase, same/other and starred/unstarred
%% axes.
\newcommand\HeShe{\gendered{He}{She}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\HeShe*{\gendered*{He}{She}\xspace}
\newcommand\heshe{\gendered{he}{she}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\heshe*{\gendered*{he}{she}\xspace}
\newcommand\SheHe{\gendered{She}{He}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\SheHe*{\gendered*{She}{He}\xspace}
\newcommand\shehe{\gendered{she}{he}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\shehe*{\gendered*{she}{he}\xspace}

\newcommand\HimHer{\gendered{Him}{Her}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\HimHer*{\gendered*{Him}{Her}\xspace}
\newcommand\himher{\gendered{him}{her}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\himher*{\gendered*{him}{her}\xspace}
\newcommand\HerHim{\gendered{Her}{Him}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\HerHim*{\gendered*{Her}{Him}\xspace}
\newcommand\herhim{\gendered{her}{him}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\herhim*{\gendered*{her}{him}\xspace}

\newcommand\HisHer{\gendered{His}{Her}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\HisHer*{\gendered*{His}{Her}\xspace}
\newcommand\hisher{\gendered{his}{her}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\hisher*{\gendered*{his}{her}\xspace}
\newcommand\HerHis{\gendered{Her}{His}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\HerHis*{\gendered*{Her}{His}\xspace}
\newcommand\herhis{\gendered{her}{his}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\herhis*{\gendered*{her}{his}\xspace}

\newcommand\HisHers{\gendered{His}{Hers}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\HisHers*{\gendered*{His}{Hers}\xspace}
\newcommand\hishers{\gendered{his}{hers}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\hishers*{\gendered*{his}{hers}\xspace}
\newcommand\HersHis{\gendered{Hers}{His}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\HersHis*{\gendered*{Hers}{His}\xspace}
\newcommand\hershis{\gendered{hers}{his}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\hershis*{\gendered*{hers}{his}\xspace}

\newcommand\HimHerself{\gendered{Himself}{Herself}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\HimHerself*{\gendered*{Himself}{Herself}\xspace}
\newcommand\himherself{\gendered{himself}{herself}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\himherself*{\gendered*{himself}{herself}\xspace}
\newcommand\HerHimself{\gendered{Herself}{Himself}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\HerHimself*{\gendered*{Herself}{Himself}\xspace}
\newcommand\herhimself{\gendered{herself}{himself}\xspace}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\herhimself*{\gendered*{herself}{himself}\xspace}

\makeatother

%% Test document:

\begin{document}

\SheHe* asked \himher to move \hisher car out of
\herhis driveway. \HeShe told \herhim that the
driveway was as much \hishers as \hershis, so
\shehe could go love \herhimself.

\SheHe* asked \himher to move \hisher car out of
\herhis driveway. \HeShe told \herhim that the
driveway was as much \hishers as \hershis, so
\shehe could go love \herhimself.

\end{document}
```

[image: Pronoun alternation example]